# How can I have a table that's responsive and without breaking words?

Tags: html, css

I want to use a table to display words and sentences, and I currently have:

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.table1 th {
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 9px;
}

td {
  word-break: break-all;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
        <th>Spanish</th>
        <th>In context</th>
        <th>Translation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>autor</td>
        <td>Stephen King es un <strong>autor</strong> muy famoso.</td>
        <td>Stephen King is a very famous <strong>author</strong>.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>favor</td>
        <td>Quiero pedirte un <strong>favor</strong>.</td>
        <td>I want to ask you a <strong>favor</strong>.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>director</td>
        <td>El <strong>director</strong> de la empresa se va de vacaciones.</td>
        <td>The <strong>director</strong> of the company is going on vacation.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

In order to avoid the width messing up with the entire page the table is on, I had to add:

```
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[image: Width breaking]

The issue is that on mobile, words break (obviously):

[image: Table view on mobile]

Is there a better way of maintaining responsiveness, not breaking the page with the width, and not breaking words?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `word-break: break-all`?

Comment: What you see in the first picture, the entire page overflows.

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to the table... Could you try and reproduce this using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)/[CodePen](https://codepen.io)/[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hello @AlejandroGoffa use `word-break: break-word;` instead of `word-break: break-all;` for demo check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: I did that and the issue persists.

Comment: Hello @AlejandroGoffa check my answer is it perfect answer to your question?

Comment: @EyalC you're right, in Code Pen it works well. I don't know what the issue is, this is the URL in case it helps: https://keyspanish.com/courses/spanish-accelerator/lesson/0-5-cognates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding `overflow-wrap: break-word` it works check the running example in below snippet and to get more information about overflow-wraohttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.table1 th {
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 9px;
}

td {
 overflow-wrap: break-word
}

tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
        <th>Spanish</th>
        <th>In context</th>
        <th>Translation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>autor</td>
        <td>Stephen King es un <strong>autor</strong> muy famoso.</td>
        <td>Stephen King is a very famous <strong>author</strong>.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>favor</td>
        <td>Quiero pedirte un <strong>favor</strong>.</td>
        <td>I want to ask you a <strong>favor</strong>.</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>director</td>
        <td>El <strong>director</strong> de la empresa se va de vacaciones.</td>
        <td>The <strong>director</strong> of the company is going on vacation.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a responsive table, add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the

Like this:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
 <table>
  ...
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm doing this:

`<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<table class="table-cognates">
<thead>
...
</table>
</div>´
But there's still overflow.

Should I apply the `{word-break: break-all; }´ class?

Comment: Yes, I think so